# Realmで複数の.realmファイルを扱っている時にMigrationで別のrealmファイルからデータを参照したい

Tags: android, java, realm

default.realmとreadonly.realmという２つのファイルを扱っている場合、default.realmのマイグレーション中にreadonly.realmに入っているデータを参照しながら更新したい場合、どのようにすれば出来るのでしょうか？

Comment: 具体的にそれぞれどんなデータ構造になっていて、どうしたいのかを追記していただけますか？マイグレーション時にそういったデータのコピーなどをするのは想定している使い方ではなく、おそらく別の方法でやる方が簡単にできるからです。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi ありがとうございます。スキーマ例としてはpost(id, alias_id, title, url)とfavorite(postId)というものがあったとして、readonly.realmにpostのデータが入っていて、default.realmにfavoriteのデータを記録するというものです。本来postオブジェクトごとfavoriteに入れたいところですが、別realmのオブジェクトを入れられないため、post.idを使って擬似的にリレーションさせてしまいました。（←元凶はここにあるでしょう）訳あってpost.alias_idをpost.idに変更したい事（これまでのpost.idは破棄）が発生し、favorite.postIdの値をpost.alias_idに相当するものに書き換えたいということがありました。
結局大した量ではなかったので、ソース上にid変換コードを書き置換させることにしてしまいました。もちろん自分の設計ミスなどから発生した事象ではありますし、realmファイルを2つに分けることのデメリットを正しく理解出来ていなかった事も今回の反省としてあります。

Answer (score 1):

マイグレーションの処理は`Migration.execute()`の中に記述していると思いますが、
その部分で通常通り`readonly.realm`用の`RealmConfiguration`を作成して`Realm.getInstance()`を呼べば`readonly.realm`用のRealmインスタンスを取得できると思います。

もしこの方法でうまくいかなければ、どのような点でうまくいかないかを追記してもらえると回答がしやすいです。

もしかしたら旧版のRealm Javaではうまくいかない点があるかもしれないですが、`0.84.1`で試した所問題なくRealmインスタンスを取得できていました。